# how to assign value to array of string in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I spent a lot of time to figure out what is the reason I get error in the following simple code. I appreciate if anyone can solve it.

```
i=0
while read line
do
    if [[ -z "$line" ]]; then
        echo "End of numbers"
        break
    else
    {
        echo "$line is not empty"
        array[$i] = $line
        echo array[$i]
        ((i += 1))  

    }
    fi
done
```

output:

```
sss
sss is not empty
command.sh: line 10: array[0]: command not found
array[0]
ss2
ss2 is not empty
command.sh: line 10: array[1]: command not found
array[1]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of:

```
array[$i] = $line
```

You need to remove spaces around `=` in BASH:

```
array[$i]="$line"
```

Or better use this syntax to append an element in array:

```
array+=( "$line" )
```